# How to make my horizontal scroll wheel scroll horizontally in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

I have a mouse that has 2 scroll wheels (Logitech MX Master 3) and I want the 2nd (horizontal) wheel to scroll horizontally in Chrome. What it does instead is navigates between the tabs. How can I rebind this?

I tried Logitech Options, but ironically it has no options for this. I also can't seem to change this in Chrome either.

Comment: It has horizontal scroll as an option… https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjRzm.png

Comment: Wow!!! Where can I find this?

Comment: in the control panel, click any of the white circles to define. Top right is a menu for "all Apps" or specific apps.

Comment: Wow it worked!!!!!! Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from the Logi Options control panel.
Click any of the white circles to see the definition pop-up.
Top right is a menu to toggle between All Apps or specific apps. [Empirically, it's better to define your globals before specific apps, that way the globals carry over initially & you can then just tweak specifics to suit each app]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't know how I didn't find these.

Comment: How can I assign a vertical scroll to my horizontal wheel? That option is not available.
I want to do it because my main wheel, the vertical one, doesn't work well.

Comment: That would be better posted as a new question - though maybe concentrate on 'How can I do this differently, because the option does not exist in the Logi Options app?'

Answer (score 0):

To use the MX Master 3 Horizontal scroll in Chrome (instead of changing tabs), select the Chrome icon in the upper right, then change the settings for that application. Do this with any other browsers/applications you may use.

[image: pic]